# GitHub user authentication in GitHub application through Django framework

Tags: django, github-api, github-app

I want to **authenticate GitHub user to my GitHub application** and serve to my local server 127.0.0.1:8000, but I am not able to take tokens.

This is how GitHub is showing [authentication](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-github-apps/authenticating-with-github-apps).

From GitHub documentation, I am not able to understand the process of authentication after generating private key, then how to create JWT and installation tokens ?

Could someone show me what to do next ?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow "[Obtaining an Access Token from a GitHub Application Webhook](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/obtain-access-token-github-app-webhook/)" ([Jerrie Pelser](https://twitter.com/jerriepelser)), which itself takes from "[JWT RSA & HMAC + ASP.NET Core](https://piotrgankiewicz.com/2017/07/24/jwt-rsa-hmac-asp-net-core/)" from [Piotr Gankiewicz](https://piotrgankiewicz.com/about-me/)

Jerrie mentions as first step to convert your PEM file to XML format.
You can use an [online tool](https://superdry.apphb.com/tools/online-rsa-key-converter) or [write a class](https://www.sneppets.com/software/how-do-i-convert-a-pem-file-to-xml-rsa-key/)

And you need your GitHub application Id:

[image: https://d33wubrfki0l68.cloudfront.net/0833e30d337eefe5d320feab78af158273127740/05e98/static/8eefe1c7f34b1a02a4a8794c16b83c92/3c051/app-identifier.png]

You will find in the article the class `JwtSecurityTokenHandler` used to create the JSON Web Token from the XML key.

[In Django](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/django+jwt+token):

```py
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny, ])
def authenticate_user(request):
 
    try:
        email = request.data['email']
        password = request.data['password']
 
        user = User.objects.get(email=email, password=password)
        if user:
            try:
                payload = jwt_payload_handler(user)
                token = jwt.encode(payload, settings.SECRET_KEY)
                user_details = {}
                user_details['name'] = "%s %s" % (
                    user.first_name, user.last_name)
                user_details['token'] = token
                user_logged_in.send(sender=user.__class__,
                                    request=request, user=user)
                return Response(user_details, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
 
            except Exception as e:
                raise e
        else:
            res = {
                'error': 'can not authenticate with the given credentials or the account has been deactivated'}
            return Response(res, status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
    except KeyError:
        res = {'error': 'please provide a email and a password'}
        return Response(res)
```

Comment: Is this using the .NET framework ?
Can I do this in Django framework ?

Comment: @SuryanshMaheshwari It is with C#. Not sure about Django, but I have found one example on the net. I have edited the answer to include it.